# How to use v-model on a list item to set an object's value

Tags: vue.js

EDIT: I just noticed that the error is coming from the v-model on the first div which is not supported by vue. However, I still don't know how to solve this.

I'm trying to generate a list of file. Each file has a choice for a material. Based on the material choice, the choices of thicknesses should change and the selection should also be saved to my object.

I currently got this working, but I'm getting an error from vue that v-model is not support on this element type.

I got a fiddle of how I implemented this here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk06wvn1/124/)

How do I solve this error or is there a better way to implement this?

I'll also paste the code bellow for those who rather read it here.

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(file,i) in files" v-model="file.fileId = i">
    <p>{{file.filename}}</p>

    <select v-model="file.selectedMaterial">
      <option disabled selected>Select material</option>
      <optgroup v-for="(alloys, name) in materials" :label="name">
        <option v-for="(thickness, alloy) in alloys" :value="[alloy, thickness]">{{alloy}}</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>

    <select v-model="file.selectedThickness">
      <option disabled selected>Select thickness</option>
      <option v-for="thickness in file.selectedMaterial[1]">{{thickness}}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
  </div>

  <p v-for="file in files">{{file}}</p>
</div>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        files: [
        {"filename": "a.dxf", "selectedMaterial":"","selectedThickness":"", "fileId":NaN},
        {"filename": "b.dxf", "selectedMaterial":"","selectedThickness":"", "fileId":NaN},
        ],

        materials: {
                "Aluminium": {
                "AW1050":[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3],
                "AW5754":[1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                "AW5083":[1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                },
          "Stainless Steel": {
                "304 / EN 1.4301": [0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12],
                "316 / EN 1.4404": [0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12]
                },
            },
        test:""

    }
})
```

Comment: Hello there! I've just posted an answer, did it helped, is it wrong or is there something else to add? Please let me know ;D If your issue is solved, do not forget to mark as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're using v-model on a `div`, which is not a form input, as stated in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements.

First you then need to remove the v-model from the `div`.

Then you'll get an warning due to setting a selected value by default via HTML, so just remove the `selected` attribute from `<option disabled selected>`.

The below snippet has the changes that I've mentioned.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        files: [
        {"filename": "a.dxf", "selectedMaterial":"","selectedThickness":"", "fileId":NaN},
        {"filename": "b.dxf", "selectedMaterial":"","selectedThickness":"", "fileId":NaN},
        ],
        
        materials: {
                "Aluminium": {
                "AW1050":[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3],
                "AW5754":[1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                "AW5083":[1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                },
          "Stainless Steel": {
                "304 / EN 1.4301": [0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12],
                "316 / EN 1.4404": [0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12]
                },
            },
        test:""
        
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(file,i) in files">
    <p>{{file.filename}}</p>
  
    <select v-model="file.selectedMaterial">
      <option disabled>Select material</option>
      <optgroup v-for="(alloys, name) in materials" :label="name">
        <option v-for="(thickness, alloy) in alloys" :value="[alloy, thickness]">{{alloy}}</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    
    <select v-model="file.selectedThickness">
      <option disabled>Select thickness</option>
      <option v-for="thickness in file.selectedMaterial[1]">{{thickness}}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
  </div>
  
  <p v-for="file in files">{{file}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Bernardo, would you be willing to take a look at another Vue Material question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952741/how-to-set-up-flexible-grid-in-vue-material

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 I totally would, but it seems that you've already found a solution, good job! Thanks for the trust ;D